# Categories best practices

Tags: ios, cocoa, categories

I am wrapping my head around using *categories* for some things where I might previously have been using inheritance.

The thing I am doing now is more of a best-practice question where I am not sure how it *should* be implemented. I am writing a category on `UIActivityIndicatorView` which basically will be used to put a activity indicator in an arbitrary view. Below you'll find the code example of how I am doing it and my main question is whether or not this is good. And I would appreciate comments on why it's bad if that is the case. Thanks.

**The category:**

```
@interface UIActivityIndicatorView (Customizations)
    - (UIActivityIndicatorView *) inView:(UIView *) target;
@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
@implementation UIActivityIndicatorView (Customizations)

- (UIActivityIndicatorView *) inView:(UIView *) target {
    [self startAnimating];
    [self setHidden:NO];
    self.frame = target.bounds;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.6f];

    return self;
}
@end
```

**Then I would use it like this:**

```
[background addSubview:[loader inView:background]];
```

I am guessing that another way of doing it would be to make an initialization function to take the container view and just return the "styled" view, or perhaps not return anything (`void`) and just let the method do the styling.

So I am looking for some guidance as to how to handle this.

Comment: I don't get where you're "making a second copy of the `UIActivityIndicatorView`".  (?)  Otherwise, I'd only suggest passing a `CGRect` instead of a `UIView` since that's all the method needs from `target`.

Comment: Yes, the "second copy" were just some confusion on my part. I'll edit that because it's confusing to anyone reading the question. About sending a `CGRect` instead of `UIView` I agree it's a good suggestion, thank you for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What kind of worries me is that I am actually making a second copy of the UIActivityIndicatorView which seem unnecessary

No, you don't. You might be confused by the fact that you are returning self from your category method, but that is just a pointer, not the object itself getting copied.

However, I would implement it slightly different:

```
- (void) addToSuperView:(UIView *) target {
    [self startAnimating];
    [self setHidden:NO];
    self.frame = target.bounds;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.6f];

    [target addSubview:self];
}
```

That way, you don't need to make an extra, unnecessary call when adding it:

```
[loader addToSuperView:background];
```

Comment: Ah, right you are, confused by that. And that makes sense. My thinking were that it would give me a hassle when removing it to add it in there. But again thinking a little bit more I see that it's a none issue, so this implementation will do just fine! Thanks for the help. (ps. looking at it it's **much** cleaner like that!)